# Kohana 3 Route :: Make a second default route?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I tried this:

```
Route::set('default_controllers', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
 ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
Route::set('default', '<uri>')
 ->defaults(array(
  'controller' => 'cms',
  'directory' => 'cms',
  'action'     => 'render',
 ));
```

But actually I want the 'default' (with the render action) to come first than the default_controllers.

I want it to first check any controllers, and if there is nothing then it should run the second default, render. Render checks the uri in the database and returns the page if exists or else it throws a error.

If i switch on the two's route position, so the 'default' route come before 'default_controllers' then it works fine with the cms pages, but not with the controllers (since it does not look for further routes, after the render function has thrown an error that the page does not exists.)

What do i do here? How can i make them both work?

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two catchall routes here. You should remove one of them, and make your routes more specific. The `(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))` route is actually very bad, and is only provided as an example.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, you have to specifically tell the route which controllers to load.

```
Route::set('default_controllers', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array(
   'controller' => 'controller|anotherController|etcController'
))
 ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

If you wanted to, you could write a class to go look for the controllers and cache the result as to not increase load times. You'd then pass this value into the value for the controller key in the array.

Your other route can remain how you had it:

```
Route::set('default', '<uri>')
 ->defaults(array(
  'controller' => 'cms',
  'directory' => 'cms',
  'action'     => 'render',
));
```